# I have to "free" rootValue, but how do I do that before returning it?

Tags: c

```
JSON_Value* createJSONObject()
{
    JSON_Value *rootValue = json_value_init_object();
    JSON_Object *rootObject = json_value_get_object(rootValue);
    return rootValue;
}
```

I can't just return rootValue, because I need to use

```
json_value_free(rootValue);
```

otherwise the memory will stay open. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't return anything you freed. (Well you can do it, but it won't work.)

State in your function contract, that the caller has to free the returned value after usage.